# why I cant start my react project after webpack updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, frontend

I updated my webpack and after that I cant start my project, that error says:

```
  The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "webpack": "4.42.0"

  Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
  However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree:

  C:\Users\SarandKala\node_modules\webpack (version: 4.43.0)

  Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you installed webpack in the parent directory (\SarandKala) of your project, instead of the project itself.

You could try navigating to C:\Users\SarandKala\ and deleting the node_modules folder that is found there, and re-running
`npm install`
*while inside* your project folder.